# Signature Pad: Capturing more than one signature

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, electronic-signature

I am using [Thomas J Bradley's Signature Pad](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/), but need it to be able to accept (and regenerate) two (or more) signatures at a time. And unfortunately, right now, I can only get the first canvas widget to accept a signature - the second canvas widget is unresponsive.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong in the Javascript section?

What do I need to change to make it accept two signatures in one form?

```
<form method="post" action="" class="sigPad"> 

<b>Signature 1:</b>
<br />

<ul class="sigNav">
    <li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear Signature</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="sig sigWrapper">
    <div class="typed"></div>
    <canvas class="pad_1" width="490" height="130"></canvas>
    <input type="hidden" name="signature_pad_output_1" class="output_1">
</div>

<br>
Typed Name: <input type="text" name="signature_name_1" value="" id="name_1" class="name_1">

<hr>

<b>Signature 2:</b>
<br />

<ul class="sigNav">
    <li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear Signature</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="sig sigWrapper">
    <div class="typed"></div>
    <canvas class="pad_2" width="490" height="130"></canvas>
    <input type="hidden" name="signature_pad_output_2" class="output_2">
</div>


<br>
Typed Name: <input type="text" name="signature_name_2" value=""  id="name_2" class="name_2">



<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var options = {
            lineTop: 100
                    , drawOnly: true
                    , canvas: '.pad_1'
                    , output: '.output_1'
                    , name: '.name_1'
        };

        $('.sigPad').signaturePad(options);

        var options = {
            lineTop: 100
                    , drawOnly: true
                    , canvas: '.pad_2'
                    , output: '.output_2'
                    , name: '.name_2'
        };

        $('.sigPad').signaturePad(options);


    });
</script>          

<script src="/includes/signature-pad/build/json2.min.js"></script>


</form>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just need to have different classes on the pads.
Instead of:

```
⋮
$('.sigPad').signaturePad(options);
⋮
$('.sigPad').signaturePad(options);
⋮
```

Change the second one to:

```
$('.sigPad2').signaturePad(options);
```

Check out the undocumented example in the downloadable package here:
https://github.com/thomasjbradley/signature-pad/blob/master/examples/accept-multiple-signatures.html

Comment: Hi thomas it is really working well.. i want to remove the line in signature pad how to remove that..

Comment: @Aravin - I know this is an ancient topic, but for posterity, add `lineColour:'#FFF'` to the options